# c# convert html content into string with utf8 encoding in win 10 universal app

Tags: c#, utf-8, win-universal-app

I want to encode the HTML content with `UTF-8`.

The Code I already have:

```
public async Task<string> MakeWebRequest()
{
    HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await http.GetAsync(**URL**);

    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Thanks for your help and time.

Dieter

Comment: What is the problem with your current code?

Comment: Encoding is done by the producer, you are the consumer here. The resulting string here will be (in-memory) Unicode. I ask as well: what is wrong with your current code?

Comment: It needed simple language conventional, and proper code(character) highlighting.

Comment: @Eser The ä in the html-content is an unknown symbol

Comment: @DieterMüller and I don't see anything in the question so that I can replicate your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know in which encoding the original string comes but try the following code:

```
public async Task<string> MakeWebRequest()
{
    var http = new HttpClient();
    var buffer = await http.GetBufferAsync(**URL**);
    var responseString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.ToArray(), 0, (int)(buffer.Length- 1));
    return responseString;
}
```

or

```
public async Task<string> MakeWebRequest()
{
    var http = new HttpClient();
    var response = await http.GetByteArrayAsync(**URL**);
    var responseString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response, 0, response.Length - 1);
    return responseString;
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but the ".Default" in the first Code in "Encoding.Default.GetBytes(str)" doesn't work. :(

Comment: This wouldn't work if the page's encoding is different than UTF8.